# Finding the equation of a rational function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a formula for a rational fuction in the form $$\frac{1}{(a(x-b)^c)}=y$$ and I am given the points $(0,30.8493),(0.75,1.1392)$, and $(1,0.2838)$. When simplifying I always seem to reach a dead end with a no solution answer. I know that there is atleast one solution because I was able to find a very close graphical solution to the problem by manimulating $a, b$, and $c$ until it worked. With my current skill level in math, I am unable to figure out this problem.

Comment: Is $c$ integral? Otherwise the function is not considered rational.

Comment: Which of the excess close parentheses on the left is the typo? I'd guess the last one, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Please rewrite the equation carefully, so that we all know what exactly it is. Secondly, I believe that it's best to approach this with a numerical method. You said that you have obtained some kind of approximate solution, so are you happy with it or not? I don't know if it's possible to solve the coefficients analytically. What I would do, is to rewrite the equations as
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
ab^c &= \frac{1}{30.8493} \\
a(0.75-b)^c &= \frac{1}{1.1392} \\
a(1-b)^c &= \frac{1}{0.2838} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and then use numerical methods to find an approximate answer.

Comment: @MattiP. We can get *almost* the exact solution  analytically (have alook at my edit). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Matti P.'s comment, use the equations
$$a\,b^c = \frac{1}{y_1}\tag 1$$
$$a \,\left(\frac{3}{4}-b\right)^c= \frac{1}{y_2}\tag 2$$
$$a \,\left(1-b\right)^c= \frac{1}{y_3}\tag 3$$

Use $(1)$ to eliminate $a$
$$a=\frac{b^{-c}}{y_1}$$ Replace in $(3)$ to get 
$$\frac{(1-b)^c b^{-c}}{y_1}=\frac{1}{y_3} \implies c=\frac{\log \left(\frac{y_1}{y_3}\right)}{\log (1-b)-\log (b)}$$

Replace in $(2)$ to get an equation in $b$. Plot it for $0 < b < 1$ and zoom more and more to "see" a solution close to $b\approx0.215$ that you could refine  using Newton method (use numerical derivatives); it would coverge very fast.

When done, go back to $a$ and $c$ to get the final results.

**Edit** *(for the fun of it)*

If you work carefully, the last equation in $b$ can rewrite
$$\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{8}{3}b\right)}{\tanh ^{-1}(1-2 b)}=\frac{\log \left(\frac{y_1}{y_2}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{y_1}{y_3}\right)}$$
Since $y_1 > y_2 > y_3$, the rhs is $<1$ making the solution to be in $\left(0,\frac 12\right)$.

To make life easier, we can *approximate* the lhs building its simplest Padé approximant at $b=\frac 14$ that is to say
$$\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{8}{3}b\right)}{\tanh ^{-1}(1-2 b)}\sim \frac{\alpha_0+\alpha_1\left(b-\frac{1}{4}\right)} {1+ \alpha_2\left(b-\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$ where
$$\alpha_0=\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\approx 0.63093$$
$$\alpha_1=-\frac{2 \left(4 \log (2) (\log (4)-9)-27 \coth ^{-1}(2) \left(\coth
   ^{-1}(3)-3\right)\right)}{3 \log \left(\frac{19683}{256}\right) \coth ^{-1}(2)}\approx -5.09907$$
$$\alpha_2=-\frac{2 \left(8 \log (2) (\log (3)-4)+9 \left(8-3 \coth ^{-1}(2)\right) \coth
   ^{-1}(2)\right)}{3 \log \left(\frac{19683}{256}\right) \coth ^{-1}(2)}\approx -4.28028$$ Using your numbers, this would give $b\approx 0.215200$ which is almost the exact solution.

Comment: Just ... wau. That's something to study for a while. Good job!

Comment: @MattiP. As I wrote, I had fun with it ! If we replace the $\frac 34$ by $x$, the lhs of the last equation is just $$\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{2 }{x}b\right)}{\tanh ^{-1}(1-2 b)}$$

Comment: @MattiP.. If fact, using graphics, the solution has to be searched for $0 < b < \frac x2$ and a linear interpolation would give as a guess $b_0=\frac{1-k}{2 x}$ where $k$ is the rhs $k=\frac{\log \left(\frac{y_1}{y_2}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{y_1}{y_3}\right)}$. Applied to the presnt case, this would give $b_0=0.1976$